# Target temperature for infused cooking oil

Tags: experimental-chemistry, temperature

A little context: I make craft chili oils for friends and family. I use a two-step infusion process. First, I infuse the oil for flavor by simmering spices in the oil held around 250 degrees Fahrenheit. Second, I add dried chili flakes into the flavored oil around 250 degrees Fahrenheit. I have used canola and grapeseed oil.

Questions: -Is there an ideal temperature to best extract flavors/fragrances from spices (for ex, from cumin seeds or star anise) into the oil?

-Do the flavor compounds deteriorate with prolonged cook times even if oil temp is kept below smoke point? For example, how does the oil change when kept at 250 degrees Fahrenheit for 1 hour vs 2 hours?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is better suited at http://cooking.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to leave the question open because it is about the extraction of fragrances, such as  4-(1-methylethyl)benzaldehyde and (*E*)-1-methoxy-4-(1-propenyl)benzene, from seeds. This about finding a suitable procedure in the chemistry of natural products and perfectly on topc!

Comment: Gowtham - Thank you. I will try posting there as well.

Comment: @Klaus Warzecha - Thank you for the vote. I think I'm looking for an answer from a solvent chemistry perspective but I lack the technical vocabulary to build a better question. Your comment was spot on though. Thank you for your time.